# How to parse in the varchar type json column?

Tags: json, parsing, hive, presto, varchar

Can you tell me how to parse in varchar type? (in Presto & Hive)

```
[{u'pageId': u'102', u'title': u'ud648', u'isBrandHomePage': 1, u'active': True, u'pageType': 1, u'type': u'page'}, {u'pageId': u'103', u'title': u'uc804uccb4 uc0c1ud488', u'isBrandHomePage': 0, u'active': True, u'pageType': 2, u'type': u'page'}, {u'pageId': u'104', u'title': u'uae30ud68duc804', u'isBrandHomePage': 0, u'active': True, u'pageType': 0, u'type': u'page'}]
```

Comment: This is not a valid json.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing in Hive: convert JSON to valid one, remove [], split on records, use json_tuple:

```
with mytable as (
 select "[{u'pageId': u'102', u'title': u'ud648', u'isBrandHomePage': 1, u'active': True, u'pageType': 1, u'type': u'page'}, {u'pageId': u'103', u'title': u'uc804uccb4 uc0c1ud488', u'isBrandHomePage': 0, u'active': True, u'pageType': 2, u'type': u'page'}, {u'pageId': u'104', u'title': u'uae30ud68duc804', u'isBrandHomePage': 0, u'active': True, u'pageType': 0, u'type': u'page'}]" json
)

select pageId,title,isBrandHomePage,active,pageType,type
from
(
select t.json, 
       regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace(
           regexp_replace(
             regexp_replace(t.json,'\\[|\\]',''),
            "u\\x27|\\x27",'"'),
         'True','true'),
        'False','false') json_fixed
  from mytable t
)s
       lateral view outer explode(split(json_fixed,'(?<=\\}), *(?=\\{)')) e as str_struct
       lateral view json_tuple(e.str_struct,'pageId','title','isBrandHomePage','active','pageType','type') x as pageId,title,isBrandHomePage,active,pageType,type
```

Result:

```
pageid  title                 isbrandhomepage   active  pagetype    type
102     ud648                 1                 true    1           page
103     uc804uccb4 uc0c1ud488 0                 true    2           page
104     uae30ud68duc804       0                 true    0           page
```

Parsing in Presto:

```
with mytable as (
 select '[{u''pageId'': u''102'', u''title'': u''ud648'', u''isBrandHomePage'': 1, u''active'': True, u''pageType'': 1, u''type'': u''page''}, {u''pageId'': u''103'', u''title'': u''uc804uccb4 uc0c1ud488'', u''isBrandHomePage'': 0, u''active'': True, u''pageType'': 2, u''type'': u''page''}, {u''pageId'': u''104'', u''title'': u''uae30ud68duc804'', u''isBrandHomePage'': 0, u''active'': True, u''pageType'': 0, u''type'': u''page''}]' json
)

select json_extract(record,'$.pageId') pageId,
       json_extract(record,'$.title') title,
       json_extract(record,'$.isBrandHomePage') isBrandHomePage,
       json_extract(record,'$.active') active,
       json_extract(record,'$.pageType') pageType,
       json_extract(record,'$.type') type
from
(
select t.json, 
       regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace(
           regexp_replace(t.json,'u\x27|\x27','"'),
         'True','true'),
        'False','false') json_fixed
  from mytable t
)s
CROSS JOIN
UNNEST( CAST(JSON_PARSE(json_fixed) AS ARRAY<JSON>) ) as x(record)
```

Result:

```
pageId  title                   isBrandHomePage active  pageType    type    
"102"   "ud648"                 1               TRUE    1           "page"
"103"   "uc804uccb4 uc0c1ud488" 0               TRUE    2           "page"
"104"   "uae30ud68duc804"       0               TRUE    0           "page"
```